# jQuery: Preventing an event from being attached more than once?

Tags: jquery

Essentially, I have an element `FOO` that I want when clicked to attach a click event to a completely separate set of elements `BAR`, so that when they're clicked they can revert `FOO` to its previous content. I only want this event attached once.

When `FOO` is clicked, its content is cached away in `$back_up`, and a trigger is added on the `BAR` set so that when clicked they can revert `FOO` back to its previous state. Is there a clever way to do this? Like to only `.bind()` if the event doesn't already exist?

```
$('<div class="noprint little check" />').click( function () {
    var $warranty_explaination = $(this).closest('.page').children('.warranty_explaination');

    var $back_up = $warranty_explaination.clone(true);
    $(this).closest('.page').find('.warranties .check:not(.noprint)').click( function () {
        /* This is the code I don't want to fire more than once */
        /*, I just want it to be set to whatever is in the $back_up */
        alert('reset'); $warranty_explaination.replaceWith( $back_up )
    } );

    $warranty_explaination.html('asdf')

} )
```

Currently, the best way I can think to do this is to attach a class, and select where that class doesn't exist.

Comment: I actually just found out about `.data()` 5 minutes after asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood, I think you are looking for the [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function to bind events.  It is just like `bind`, except it removes the handler after the first invoke.

Alternatively, you could store a flag in [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and look for it within your click handler.

Comment: `$.one()` ring to rule them all... anyway, the OP said "attached once," which sounds to me like "bind once," not "execute the callback once.

Comment: @Bears Yeah I see your point; I was unable to determine for sure what he/she meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can unbind handlers for a given event from an element using unbind.

```
$(this).closest('.page').find('.warranties .check:not(.noprint)').unbind("click");
$(this).closest('.page').find('.warranties .check:not(.noprint)').click(function() ...
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unbind